# Web Application Performance Testing - End User Experience

Tags: web-server, asp.net, performance-monitoring, web, web-applications

I currently maintain servers that host a .NET web application for external customers (primarily Microsoft technologies).   I would like to find some tools or services that would let me measure web application response time and/or end user experience with our application (i.e page load times, http errors, etc. etc.)  I would like to be able to analyze application performance trends and create reports from this data.  Anything that can be scheduled to run on a regular basis would be great.  Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LoadRunner measures response times. Kinda expensive.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried capsa?It can measure the response time and diagnose the the http errors.what's more, it can generate the reports according to your requests.Wireshark is good,too, however, it do not have the reporting function, the others are too expensive.

Answer (score 0):

Expensive is relative and should be considered against the financial risk not meeting scalability requirements.   For some environments even the most expensive tool is cheap compared to the risk of the application not scaling and the associated financial risk of this event: Think of your website failing on the largest shopping day of the year and your competitors getting your cast off business.

Depending upon the technologies involved in your performance testing you may have many tool options available from open source through commercial.    But whatever tool route you go be sure it meets the following

- It can exercise your interfaces just as a user would
- The reporting for the tool matches what you need to report against your requirements and is conducive to finding bottlenecks in your environment
- Your staff has the skills to use the tool successfully
- Your management is willing to invest in training and a mentor for your first 2-3 engagements

Get a mismatch on any of the above and you may as well have purchased the most expensive performance testing tool on the market and hired the most expensive consulting firm to deploy it even if you are using a "free (as in beer)" performance test tool.

Answer (score 0):

You should try some of the RUM (Real User Monitoring) services such as http://www.gear5.me (requires simple javascript) or http://www.newrelic.com (requres server module). There are few dozens of similar services available on net, but all of them measure load times from the perspective of users.